# When to use 來源於 and when to use 來自於

Tags: word-choice

Recently, on a language exchange platform, I tried to describe one of my favourite books (Thucydides, from which I had to study many passages) as follows:

> 我所喜歡的書頗多，包含古希臘的經文在內。比如說希臘歷史學家修昔底德的傑作《伯羅奔尼撒戰爭》。它以一次內戰為题目，敘述它的來源和發展。大家討論的「修昔底德陷阱」也來源於此。

Native speakers made several corrections, but I think it is more useful for future users if I split them into different questions.

The correction that left me most desperate and frankly shook my conviction that I can ever bring my Chinese to an intermediate level, was when I was told to replace 來源於 with  with 來自於。From a Google search it appears that some people at least don’t mind describing the origin of names with 來源於. See [here](http://www.360doc.com/content/18/0911/23/32901809_785820728.shtml), where the title reads:

> 好名字来源于典故，看看你的名字来源于哪里

But, if I google “这条信息来源于“, many hits are from the same text. Must I only use 來源於 with names and not with most other forms of verbal information? Even a phrase such „Thucydides‘ Trap“? I am very confused!

Answer (score 1):

来源于 - (?) comes from. The (?) is something intangible, such as knowledge, concept, story. Name is the symbol of something and is considered intangible.

來自於 - (?) comes from. The (?) is something tangible, an item, goods, commodity...

Comment: Doesn’t this imply I should use 来源于， as I did and not 来自于， as the correction suggested?!

Comment: 信息 is "information", which is intangible.  If you mean to say "the letter came from...", then "來自於" is correct, as the letter is written on a piece of paper, that is tangible. Hope this helps to clear the confusion.

Comment: If you mean the information came from the "Thucydides Trap", then correct.

Comment: Yes, correct, but note the typo (my dictionary told me so :)

Comment: totally right. As a Greek, I know of course how it’s written, but when I start it, my iPad proposes the wrong one!

Answer (score 1):

源 means source as in 起源、來源。

來自於/來自 means where something comes from.
源自於/源於/源自 means where something originates from.

One might say "This orange comes from California 這顆柳橙來自於加州." Since citrus fruit  originated from southern China, I would not say 柳橙源於加州, which means, incorrectly, orange first evolved/appeared in California.

I can accept 來自於、來自、源自於、源自 and 源於．來源於 is new to me.

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting point that the whole combination 來源於 is weird for some speakers!